# Decomposition of an integral operator into a composition

Tags: operator-theory, integral-operators, fa.functional-analysis

I've been musing about the following question for a while now. Given an integral operator $G$ defined by
$$ (Gf)(x) = \int_0^1 G(x,u) f(u)\,du $$
Is it possible to decompose this into two separate "one-sided" integral operators $L$ and $R$ such that
$$ (Gf)(x) = \int_x^1 L(x,u) \int_0^x R(u,v) f(v)\,dv\,du $$
If so, under what assumptions on $G$? And are there expressions for the left and right operators $L$ and $R$ in terms of $G$?

Comment: So you want a continuous analog of the decomposition of matrices into lower and upper triangular matrices. I'm not a specialist, but it seems to me that for reasonably nice kernels (e.g. Hilbert-Schmidt), the natural approach should be: pass to the limit in the decomposition for finite dimensional approximations, and show that the sequence of factors admits a converging subsequence.  

Comment: @Pietro Majer: Matrixes can not be decomposed in a product of upper triangular and lower triangular matrices (look up Bruhat decomposition). You have to allow permutation matrices. But nice interpretation of the question.

Comment: Is the upper limit of the inner integral $x$ or $u.$ ? 

Comment: @Uday: The upper limit is $x$. @Pietro: This was indeed inspired by the LU decomposition. I'm wondering how to construct the analogous functional form of the decomposition.

Comment: @MarcPalm:  of course, I'not saying that. The OP ask under what assumptions on G it is possible; I'm saying that the infinite dimensional problem includes the analogous problem for matrices, etc.

Comment: The upper limit $x$ screws the problem up because then $Gf(x)$ depends only on $f(t)$ with $t\le x$, which is possible only if the operator is triangular from the beginning, i.e., when there is nothing to do really. You'd better put $u$ there as Uday suggested.

Comment: Two modest remarks.  Firstly one would need to know on which spaces (presumably suitable $L^2$-spaces) your spaces are acting on and what regularity or growth properties you are demanding from the kernels, in order to attack the problem rigorously.  Secondly, operators with triangular kernels tend to be quasi-nilpotent and so anintegral operator which cannot be expressed as product of two such operators would be counter-example.

Comment: I heard that the [chebfun2 package](http://www.chebfun.org/docs/guide/guide11.html) for MATLAB can perform some kind of LU decomposition for functions defined on the unit square…

Answer (score 1):

imho, if you can rewrite the equation in a suitable basis, you  obtain an infinite matrix and may try the QR decomposition. Try wavelet basis or a parent of this family of functions like curvelets, ridglets... regarding properties of the operators $G$. If $G$ is a pseudo or Fourier integral operator, these bases are known to give almost diagonal representations.

Answer (score 1):

To mimic multiplication, the middle integral you wrote down should be from $0$ to $u$, not from $0$ to $x$. The way you have written it, $f(v)$ does not affect $Gf(x)$ unless $v \leq x$.

Assuming $G, L,$ and $R$ are sufficiently nice smooth functions, we should have some kind of uniqueness result where an equality of integral operators is an equality of integrals, and so we can write

$G(x,v) = \int_{\max (x,v)}^1  L(x,u) R(u,v) du$

If $L$ and $R$ are honest bounded functions, this gives $G(x,v)=0$ if $x=1$ or $v=1$, which is problematic.

So you must put some vanishing condition on $G$ or use unbounded $L$, $R$.